# How to set the time on an emulator from inside DDMS?

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms

How do you set the time of the emulator from inside of DDMS? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this shell script to set the time on my emulator:

```
#!/bin/bash
adb shell date $(date --date="$1" +%s)
```

The script takes one argument, the date that you want to set the emulator too. For more information, checkout the [date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_%28Unix%29) command.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the emulator like a normal Android device and set the time from there?

Comment: For screenshot generation during testing.. go figure. :)

Comment: I'm just so much not a unix guy >_< hate using those shell commands but makes sence :)